# Multi-user mass image uploads with PHP

Tags: php

I'll soon be building a competition microsite which is based entirely around image uploads: in order to enter, users will need to upload an image.

I've previously built a similar website on top of a PHP MVC framework, which worked awesomely up until a couple of hours before the competition was due to close, where a rush of last minute entries caused the server to crash, rendering the website inaccessible. The files being uploaded were pretty large in some instances (images scanned by the average user, many of whom did not know about optimizing file sizes).

I'd obviously like to avoid this issue the best I can with this new project, and would appreciate tips on how to build a robust site that won't crash when the last minute rush of entries comes through.

Comment: Well, the best thing would be to have a scalable cloud, I think that would be the only possibility in case of extreme server load. You can beat hardware only with more hardware :D

Answer (score 3):

That's hard to answer. You'll just have to figure out where exactly the bottleneck is in your app and improve that particular part. Is it the webserver itself which is flooded with too many simultaneous, long running connections? Then tune the server to accept fewer connections at once and account for it in your front-end somehow, use a different kind of server, use a beefier server or use multiple load-balanced servers. Or is it whatever post-processing you're doing? Then optimize that to not process hundreds of images at the same time, but use a queue-worker system or farm out the processing work to other servers. Or is it the amount of images being downloaded? Then you may want to look at a CDN.

Again, *analyze* what the problem is and look for a specific solution to it.

Comment: Thank you - this is pretty helpful. I think it may be a combination of both, and the post-processing aspect is something I will definitely revisit on this build.